# Anyway to provide custom PagedResourcesAssembler implementation?

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am under a requirement of exclude the "first" and "last" in the _links section of the response. Based on the spring data rest code, it seems I should provide custom PagedResourcesAssembler implementation to achieve this.

I try to subclass RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration to "overrides" the pageableResolver bean but with no luck. No error occurs but the "first" and "last" property is still returned. You can get the code at [my github repo](https://github.com/pkuashi/spring-data-rest-poc)

Anybody have a solution here?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't went through your solution on github step by step, but it seems you only have overridden only one `toResource` method in the `PagedResourceAssembler`.

However that's an overloaded method, and I assume most of the time the other variants are called.

So, simply override all of the others too:

```
public PagedResources<Resource<T>> toResource(Page<T> entity);
public PagedResources<Resource<T>> toResource(Page<T> page, Link selfLink);
public <R extends ResourceSupport> PagedResources<R> toResource(Page<T> page, ResourceAssembler<T, R> assembler);
public <R extends ResourceSupport> PagedResources<R> toResource(Page<T> page, ResourceAssembler<T, R> assembler, Link link);
```

**Oh, and don't forget to override all of the `toEmptyResource` methods too!**